# How to lowercase a region in gboard?

Tags: gboard, text-input

Let's say you're using voice typing, and you FORGOT THAT YOU LEFT THE CAPS LOCK BUTTON ACTIVATED AND NOW YOU GOT A WHOLE REGION OF WORDS IN CAPITAL LETTERS! IT MIGHT GO ON AND ON FOR VERY LONG WHILE DEPENDING ON HOW LONG IT TOOK BEFORE YOU LOOKED BACK DOWN and noticed what you were typing...

So okay, we select this big block of words, then what do we do to get them back into normal/mixed or lower case? Thanks.

Currently the only thing I know how to do is just delete the region and start all over again.

Comment: Unrelated to Android at all, but I usually use https://convertcase.net/ to quickly fix all UPPERCASE/lowercase text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gboard has a feature for the past 4-5 years that allows to select a word, then pressing the Shift key to change the word's casing. However, during my testing with multiple words or sentences, I found out that only up to seven words can be selected.

[image]